# Why Spring Boot 1.4.x doesn't load spring.profiles: profile1, default (with blank space)

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have the following configuration (application.yml):

```
spring:
  profiles: dev, default
myorg:
  myvalue: hello world
```

Now I want to read the `myorg.myvalue` property

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ...... {
    .......

    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner getRunner(Environment env){
        return (args) -> {
            System.out.println("myorg.myvalue is:" 
                             + env.getProperty("myorg.myvalue"));
        };
    }
```

I got the following output

```
myorg.myvalue is: null
```

But when I run the same application but using Spring Boot `1.5.x` I get the expected result:

```
myorg.myvalue is: hello world
```

If I want to get the expected result in Spring Boot `1.4.x` I have to change the `application.yml` to  (removing blank space)

```
spring:
  profiles: dev,default
myorg:
  myvalue: hello world
```

After that I was looking for a difference between version `1.4.x` and `1.5.x` at [github](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/compare/1.4.x...1.5.x) and there is a class called `SpringProfileDocumentMatcher` is located inside the `org.springframework.boot.yaml` package.

I would like to know if the changes made on `SpringProfileDocumentMatcher` class from Spring boot `1.4.x` to `1.5.x` is the only reason why I get different results when I try to read the property .yml file on the scenario when the `spring.profiles` has a blank space between coma separated values.

For example in Spring `1.5.x` in the `SpringProfileDocumentMatcher` there is a method called `extractSpringProfiles` that can return the list of the profiles without the blank space beteween the coma in the `spring.profiles property`.

```
private List<String> extractSpringProfiles(Properties properties) {
    SpringProperties springProperties = new SpringProperties();
    MutablePropertySources propertySources = new MutablePropertySources();
    propertySources.addFirst(new PropertiesPropertySource("profiles", properties));
    PropertyValues propertyValues = new PropertySourcesPropertyValues(
            propertySources);
    new RelaxedDataBinder(springProperties, "spring").bind(propertyValues);
    List<String> profiles = springProperties.getProfiles();
    return profiles;
}`
```

It this the main reason why I get different results between version `1.4.x` and `1.5.x`?  or Am I missing something in this analysis?

Hope you can help me with this doubt.

Thank you.

Comment: Looks like you've done all the sleuthing yourself already. Do you need us to find the exact pull request that fixed this bug? Here you go: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/pull/5561/commits

Comment: thank you very much that is I was looking for!! you help me to clarify this doubt.